# Using Sql to get result from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, database

TABLE1

```
-id-----name----partid
 1     DDU       2 
 2     FDK       4
 3     DDU       3
```

TABLE2

```
-partid----Amount-----
 2          600
 3          400
 4          500
```

After the query, This is how i want my table to look like

```
name          amount
DDU            1000
```

Note: The 1000 for DDU IS GOTTEN BY ADDING 600 AND 400. How do i achieve this using my sql query. Partid is a foreign key in Table1 and Primary Key of table2

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`, `SUM()`.

Comment: And you don't want (FDK, 500 )in the returned result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT t.name,SUM(s.amount)
FROM Table1 t
JOIN Table2 s
 ON(t.partid = s.partid)
GROUP BY t.name
```

You also should get `FDK 500` in your result set , so I assume you need a `WHERE` clause ?

```
WHERE t.name = 'DDU'
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following query:

```
select TABLE1.name, sum(TABLE2.amount) 
from TABLE1 inner join TABLE2 on TABLE2.partid = TABLE1.partid
group by TABLE1.name
```